# Do you have to install disc games to play them on an Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I want to buy all of the Halo games for the 360 on disc, but do I need free space to install them? I've never had an Xbox before.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to install any arbitrary 360 game. Some games require some degree of installation. I'd have to check each of the games in question specifically.

Comment: The only game I remember you having to install was GTA V.  I'm sure there are others, but the rest ran off disc.  You _can_ install the games optionally to improve their performance.

Comment: It depends on the game; Loading times will be increased; No Halo game on the 360 required it

Comment: I heard that Halo 3 used to copy its data from DVD to HDD, which became a problem when MS implemented the install system, since the game would then copy data from HDD to HDD. Halo 3 was one of the few games, where it was recommended it should *not* be installed.

Answer (score 3):

You don't, in general, have to install disc games to play them on an Xbox 360, although it will often make the load times faster.

Some games do require installation, but the Halo games are not among those. Indeed, Halo 3 should *not* be installed, because it's optimized to run faster from the disc.

You do, however, need to have a little free space on your hard drive in order to create save data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need disk space to save game data on your Console.
The best thing to do is get rid of data you don't need anymore, or go through the games one at a time. If the console comes up with a 'no free space' error it should give you an option to delete some data.